# How to match all 4byte UTF-8 characters in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I've tried a lot of variations, like `/[\u0FFF-\uFFFF]/`, but it never worked for me as I expected.

The reason why I ask is because the `mysql` version I use doesn't support these characters, and cuts strings when there is an emoticon or something like that. Updating the mysql for the new version is not a solution at the moment.

Comment: Can you give some samples on which we can try on?

Comment: Perhaps, you need to match any non-ASCII char? Try `/[^\x00-\x7F]+/g`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description), code points U+10000   to U+10FFFF are encoded with 4 bytes.

With a recent enough Node version (v6, perhaps v5 as well but I didn't test), you can use those in a regular expression like this (notice the `u` flag):

```
const str = 'hello world!';

console.log( /[\u{10000}-\u{10FFFF}]/u.test(str) );         // true
console.log( str.replace(/[\u{10000}-\u{10FFFF}]/gu, '') ); // `hello world!`
```

(more info [here](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es6-unicode-regex))